# Android OnClickListener, intent and context

Tags: java, android, this, onclicklistener, android-context

I am new to java and android. Here I am trying to set up my onclicklistener so when clicked, it will show another activity, i.e. ActivityB.class. The problem is with `Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);` I am not sure what to put there for `context`. I tried to use `this` and `context`, and both are wrong.

Could you please kindly explain when and why I should use `this` and when to use other terms for the `context`?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
            startActivity(i);
            }
        }); 

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the code to.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

As you need to pass context while using intent.

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly. i seem to be able to use getApplicationContext() and still works. what is the difference between MainActivity.this and getApplicationContext()? Thanks again!

Comment: @JeffLam search on stackoverflow there is a good explanation on this by commonsware

Comment: There are two type of context in Android.  Activity context and application context. In case you don't have the activity context then application context should be useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class));
    }
});
```

Fastest method!
Hope it helps! :D

Answer (score 1):

1) Replace context with getApplicationContext()

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);

           startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

2) Replace context with MainActivity.this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityB.class);

           startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

If you declare `ActivityB.class` in manifest this should work.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(i);
```